# Why the gulp scss throws error?

Tags: macos, sass, gulp

When I run 'gulp scss' on my mac it reports while there's no such error on another mac with same version of gulp (3.8.11):

```
[16:40:32] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/codes/biz-tools/portal/gulpfile.js
[16:40:32] Starting 'scss'...

stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: Command line usage error
    at createExecError (/Users/zhun.qu/Documents/codes/biz-tools/portal/node_modules/gulp-scsslint/src/index.js:155:33)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/zhun.qu/Documents/codes/biz-tools/portal/node_modules/gulp-scsslint/src/index.js:217:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
```

But it's ok on my mac if i comment two lines in gulpfile.js

```
 gulp.task('scss', function() {
   return gulp.src(paths.styles)
   //    .pipe(scsslint())
   //    .pipe(scsslint.reporter())
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('src/styles'));
});
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Below is the entire gulpfile

```
// Project configuration
var project         = 'unlock', // Project name, used for build zip.
    url         = 'http://localhost:8888', // Local Development URL for BrowserSync. Change as-needed.
    bower       = './assets/bower_components/'; // Not truly using this yet, more or less playing right now. TO-DO Place in Dev branch
    build       = './buildtheme/', // Files that you want to package into a zip go here
    buildInclude    = [
                // include common file types
                '**/*.php',
                '**/*.html',
                '**/*.css',
                '**/*.js',
                '**/*.svg',
                '**/*.ttf',
                '**/*.otf',
                '**/*.eot',
                '**/*.woff',
                '**/*.woff2',

                // include specific files and folders
                'screenshot.png',

                // exclude files and folders
                '!node_modules/**/*',
                '!assets/bower_components/**/*',
                '!style.css.map',
                '!assets/js/custom/*',
                '!assets/css/partials/*'

            ];

// Load plugins
    var gulp     = require('gulp'),
        browserSync  = require('browser-sync'), // Asynchronous browser loading on .scss file changes
        reload       = browserSync.reload,
        autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'), // Autoprefixing magic
        minifycss    = require('gulp-uglifycss'),
        filter       = require('gulp-filter'),
        uglify       = require('gulp-uglify'),
        imagemin     = require('gulp-imagemin'),
        newer        = require('gulp-newer'),
        rename       = require('gulp-rename'),
        concat       = require('gulp-concat'),
        notify       = require('gulp-notify'),
        cmq          = require('gulp-combine-media-queries'),
        runSequence  = require('gulp-run-sequence'),
        sass         = require('gulp-sass'),
        plugins      = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ camelize: true }),
        ignore       = require('gulp-ignore'), // Helps with ignoring files and directories in our run tasks
        rimraf       = require('gulp-rimraf'), // Helps with removing files and directories in our run tasks
        zip          = require('gulp-zip'), // Using to zip up our packaged theme into a tasty zip file that can be installed in WordPress!
        plumber      = require('gulp-plumber'), // Helps prevent stream crashing on errors
        cache        = require('gulp-cache'),
        sourcemaps   = require('gulp-sourcemaps');


/**
 * Browser Sync
 *
 * Asynchronous browser syncing of assets across multiple devices!! Watches for changes to js, image and php files
 * Although, I think this is redundant, since we have a watch task that does this already.
*/
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    var files = [
                    '**/*.php',
                    '**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'
                ];
    browserSync.init(files, {

        // Read here http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/
        proxy: url,

        // port: 8080,

        // Tunnel the Browsersync server through a random Public URL
        // tunnel: true,

        // Attempt to use the URL "http://my-private-site.localtunnel.me"
        // tunnel: "ppress",

        // Inject CSS changes
        injectChanges: true

    });
});



/**
 * Styles
 *
 * Looking at src/sass and compiling the files into Expanded format, Autoprefixing and sending the files to the build folder
 *
 * Sass output styles: https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/06/15/different-sass-output-styles/
*/
gulp.task('styles', function () {
        gulp.src('./assets/css/*.scss')
                .pipe(plumber())
                .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                .pipe(sass({
                    errLogToConsole: true,

                    //outputStyle: 'compressed',
                    outputStyle: 'compact',
                    // outputStyle: 'nested',
                    // outputStyle: 'expanded',
                    precision: 10
                }))
                .pipe(sourcemaps.write({includeContent: false}))
                .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
                .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', '> 1%', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
                .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
                .pipe(plumber.stop())
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
                .pipe(filter('**/*.css')) // Filtering stream to only css files
                .pipe(cmq()) // Combines Media Queries
                .pipe(reload({stream:true})) // Inject Styles when style file is created
                .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
                .pipe(minifycss({
                    maxLineLen: 80
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
                .pipe(reload({stream:true})) // Inject Styles when min style file is created
                .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete', onLast: true }))
});


/**
 * Scripts: Vendors
 *
 * Look at src/js and concatenate those files, send them to assets/js where we then minimize the concatenated file.
*/
gulp.task('vendorsJs', function() {
    return  gulp.src(['./assets/js/vendor/*.js', bower+'**/*.js'])
                .pipe(concat('vendors.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js'))
                .pipe(rename( {
                    basename: "vendors",
                    suffix: '.min'
                }))
                .pipe(uglify())
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js/'))
                .pipe(notify({ message: 'Vendor scripts task complete', onLast: true }));
});


/**
 * Scripts: Custom
 *
 * Look at src/js and concatenate those files, send them to assets/js where we then minimize the concatenated file.
*/

gulp.task('scriptsJs', function() {
    return  gulp.src('./assets/js/custom/*.js')
                .pipe(concat('custom.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js'))
                .pipe(rename( {
                    basename: "custom",
                    suffix: '.min'
                }))
                .pipe(uglify())
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js/'))
                .pipe(notify({ message: 'Custom scripts task complete', onLast: true }));
});


/**
 * Images
 *
 * Look at src/images, optimize the images and send them to the appropriate place
*/
gulp.task('images', function() {

// Add the newer pipe to pass through newer images only
    return  gulp.src(['./assets/img/raw/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'])
                .pipe(newer('./assets/img/'))
                .pipe(rimraf({ force: true }))
                .pipe(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 7, progressive: true, interlaced: true }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/img/'))
                .pipe( notify( { message: 'Images task complete', onLast: true } ) );
});


/**
 * Clean gulp cache
 */
 gulp.task('clear', function () {
   cache.clearAll();
 });


 /**
  * Clean tasks for zip
  *
  * Being a little overzealous, but we're cleaning out the build folder, codekit-cache directory and annoying DS_Store files and Also
  * clearing out unoptimized image files in zip as those will have been moved and optimized
 */

 gulp.task('cleanup', function() {
    return  gulp.src(['./assets/bower_components', '**/.sass-cache','**/.DS_Store'], { read: false }) // much faster
                .pipe(ignore('node_modules/**')) //Example of a directory to ignore
                .pipe(rimraf({ force: true }))
                // .pipe(notify({ message: 'Clean task complete', onLast: true }));
 });
 gulp.task('cleanupFinal', function() {
    return  gulp.src(['./assets/bower_components','**/.sass-cache','**/.DS_Store'], { read: false }) // much faster
                .pipe(ignore('node_modules/**')) //Example of a directory to ignore
                .pipe(rimraf({ force: true }))
                // .pipe(notify({ message: 'Clean task complete', onLast: true }));
 });

 /**
  * Build task that moves essential theme files for production-ready sites
  *
  * buildFiles copies all the files in buildInclude to build folder - check variable values at the top
  * buildImages copies all the images from img folder in assets while ignoring images inside raw folder if any
  */

  gulp.task('buildFiles', function() {
    return  gulp.src(buildInclude)
                .pipe(gulp.dest(build))
                .pipe(notify({ message: 'Copy from buildFiles complete', onLast: true }));
  });


/**
* Images
*
* Look at src/images, optimize the images and send them to the appropriate place
*/
gulp.task('buildImages', function() {
    return  gulp.src(['assets/img/**/*', '!assets/images/raw/**'])
                .pipe(gulp.dest(build+'assets/img/'))
                .pipe(plugins.notify({ message: 'Images copied to buildTheme folder', onLast: true }));
});

 /**
  * Zipping build directory for distribution
  *
  * Taking the build folder, which has been cleaned, containing optimized files and zipping it up to send out as an installable theme
 */
 gulp.task('buildZip', function () {
    // return   gulp.src([build+'/**/', './.jshintrc','./.bowerrc','./.gitignore' ])
    return  gulp.src(build+'/**/')
                .pipe(zip(project+'.zip'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
                .pipe(notify({ message: 'Zip task complete', onLast: true }));
 });


 // ==== TASKS ==== //
 /**
  * Gulp Default Task
  *
  * Compiles styles, fires-up browser sync, watches js and php files. Note browser sync task watches php files
  *
 */

 // Package Distributable Theme
 gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
    runSequence('styles', 'cleanup', 'vendorsJs', 'scriptsJs',  'buildFiles', 'buildImages', 'buildZip','cleanupFinal', cb);
 });


 // Watch Task
 gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'vendorsJs', 'scriptsJs', 'images', 'browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch('./assets/img/raw/**/*', ['images']);
    gulp.watch('./assets/css/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('./assets/js/**/*.js', ['scriptsJs', browserSync.reload]);

 });
```

Comment: Can you post your Gulpfile.js?

Comment: I've post the code which failed the gulp scss.